# Fiddler not capturing traffic from locust.io v1.1.1

Tags: python, fiddler, locust

Capturing locust traffic in Fiddler with Locust version 0.11 works just fine.  Using a python virtual (3.7) and PyCharm.

I created a second python virtual (also 3.7) for the latest version of Locust v1.1.1.  Execution of this version of Locust captured no traffic in Fiddler.

In Fiddler I reset The certificate :

```
Tools -> Options - HTTPS - Actions
```

Within PyCharm I've tried both Auto-detect proxy and Manual config under:

```
Settings -> Appearance and Behavior -> System Settings -> HTTP Proxy
```

Flipping the virtual env back to the locust 0.11 traces traffic in Fiddler just fine.  I don't know what v1.1.1 may be doing differently.  Fiddler logs do not show any sign an attempt to connect.

Curious if anyone has encountered similar behavior.

Comment: If locust uses HTTPS you have to add the Fiddler root certificate to Python, as Python does not use the Windows certificate store and therefore does not trust the Fiddler root CA certificate automatically.

Comment: @Robert thank you for the reply.  I do believe that is my issue but everything appears in place.  I see the cert from Fiddler in Pycharm.  Also the previous locust version remains tracing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think this is a certificate issue at all (if it was, the request would not go thru)

Locust configures `requests` to ignore proxy settings, see  https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/writing-a-locustfile.html#http-proxy-settings

You can probably re-enable it, but you’ll need to check either locust source or requests documentation.

Comment: GIGANTIC thank you!  I flipped it to true in users.py tracing appeared.